# Java: In a string, how to extract a number that precedes a regex match?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that contains a fraction of 100. The string looks like this:

```
blah
SCORE
95 / 100
USAGE
1.4GB / Unlimited
blah
```

I want to get the value that is before " / 100". In the above case, this value would be 95. But it can be any number between 0 and 100.

I know that if I use the following regex expression matches the " / 100" portion of the string. What I need to know is how to get the number that precedes this match.

```
\s\/\s100
```

Comment: Just use [this solution](http://ideone.com/ZoqiCN).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a positive lookahead in order to make digits preceded by that pattern.

In the expression below, "95" would be in the capturing group.

```
\b(\d+)\b(?= \/ 100\b)
```

- `\b` - Word boundary to ensure that the digit isn't surrounded by any other characters.
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group to match one or more digits.
- `(?= \/ 100\b)` - Positive lookahead to match the preceeding digits if they are followed by `/ 100`.

---

> But it can be any number between 0 and 100.

If the number has to be between 0 and 100, use could also use the following:

```
\b(\d{1,2}|100)\b(?= \/ 100\b)
```

- `\d{1,2}|100` matches a number between 0-100
- The rest is the same as the example above.

Comment: `(\d+)(?=\s\/\s100)` will also extract the digit(s) if followed by a space+`/`+space+`1000`. Also, there is no point in using a capturing group around the whole matching pattern, you can always use `.group(0)` to get that value. Actually, a capturing solution would be more efficient than a lookaround-based one.

Comment: One more observation: the lookahead `(?!\d)` is redundant in `\b(\d{1,2}(?!\d)|100)\b` because the right-hand context is defined.

Comment: No need to escape the forward slash - it has no special regex meaning

Comment: @Bohemian I just escaped it because I was testing on https://regex101.com and it would otherwise throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is only one `XX / 100` (where `XX` can be `100` or a 1- or 2-digit integer) in your string and it appears at the beginning of some line, you can safely use

```
"(?m)^(100|\\d{1,2})\\s*/\\s*100\\b"
```

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/ZoqiCN):

```
String str = "blah\nSCORE\n95 / 100\nUSAGE\n1.4GB / Unlimited\nblah";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(100|\\d{2})\\s*/\\s*100\\b");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
} // => 95
```

*The regex matches*:

- `(?m)^` - start of a line (since `(?m)` enables a multiline mode when `^` matches a line start rather than a string start) that is followed by...
- `(100|\\d{1,2})` - a *capturing group #1* that matches `100` or any 1 or 2 digits
- `\\s*/\\s*` - zero or more whitespaces followed by `/` followed by  zero or more whitespaces
- `100\\b` - a whole word `100` (that is, there can be no more digits, or even letters and an underscore `_` right after).

**Note** that the value is *captured* (due to a paire of unescaped parentheses `(...)`) into Group 1 that we get with `matcher.group(1)` after executing the matcher. Capturing is more appropriate for this task since you need no overlapping matches where lookarounds are necessary, and they are less efficient than capturing.